# How can get method selector from function call string in objective-c?

Tags: ios, c, objective-c, macros

In fact, My situations is I want to find a simple and elegant style to call a optional protcol method.

When I have a protcol like this:

```
@protocol SubModuleProtocol <NSObject>
@optional
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView;
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView;
@end
```

The recommend call style is this:

```
id <SubModuleProtocol> subModule = xxx;
if ([subModule respondsToSelector:@selector(scrollViewWillBeginDragging:)]) {
    [subModule scrollViewWillBeginDragging:nil];
}
```

I think the way is too troublesome if there are many method in protocol.
So I want write a macro to call.
First I use macro like:

```
#define SAFECALL(object,sel,func) \
if ([object respondsToSelector:sel]) { \
[object func];\
}
```

You can use:

```
SAFECALL(subModule, @selector(scrollViewWillBeginDragging:), scrollViewWillBeginDragging:nil);
```

The way still a little troublesome.
I want a macro like this:

```
#define SAFECALL(object,func) \
if ([object respondsToSelector:**Get Selector from func**]) { \
[object func];\
}
```

May be use c string analysis can realize it。but it looks not a smart way。
So what is the best way to solve it.Or better ways to do safecall than use marco.

Answer (score 0):

not ideal to use a macro for app logic but you could use the following..

```objectivec
#define CALL_IF_RESPONDS_TO_SEL(o,s) if([o respondsToSelector:@selector(s)]) \
 {SEL sel=@selector(s); \
 IMP imp=[o methodForSelector:sel]; \
 void(*fn)(id,SEL)=(void*)imp; \
 fn(o,sel);}
```

this one clearly does not handle object messages apart from calling the method on the object.

If you use that to often you will regret..
In example

```
CALL_IF_RESPONDS_TO_SEL(someobj,withParam:andParam:); // <-- does not work as is!
CALL_IF_RESPONDS_TO_SEL(someobj,withParam); // <-- should work
CALL_IF_RESPONDS_TO_SEL(someobj,withParam:); // <-- see, easy bug!
```

So it is not troublesome on the amount of available methods of a protocol but troublesome on methods that have an argument or multiple arguments, because for those a simple function call will not work as expected.

While including app logic in a macro can make life easier if the methods you invoke have always the same amount of messages involved, it is still much safer and easier to debug to just implement protocol safety checks properly as a normal method.

or you integrate the following to be able to use objects on method calls

```objectivec
#define CALL_IF_RESPONDS_TO_SEL(o,s,param) if([o respondsToSelector:@selector(s)]) \
 SEL sel = @selector(s); \
 [o performSelector:sel withObject:param];}
```

in that case `param` can also be `nil` and selector `s` would end with `:`.

Comment: Thanks your answer。
"performSelector" is often insufficient because it only allow two paramters at most。And The most important thing is that I want use the compiler to check the parameters。"performSelector" and "msg_send" have lost that ability.

Comment: blunt spoken, when using the delegate design pattern sending objects is anyway insufficient despite widely used. When object sending is involved i would not use a macro making things more difficult to debug. The first macro could be extended to support multiple objects, but still, debugging gets worse. Also using respondsToSelector means you do not have a delegate setter in use, which is better anyway do keep things apart.